# gnome-control-center won't open after upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome-control-center

Ever since I upgrade Ubuntu to 20.04 I get an error when trying to open gnome-control-center:

```
 gnome-control-center: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-
gnu/libclutter-gtk-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: 
clutter_wayland_stage_set_wl_surface
```

I already tried reinstalling gnome-control-center and libclutter-gtk, as suggested on a similar problem but that didn't work either.

The output of `apt-cache policy libclutter-gtk-1.0-0` is:

```
libclutter-gtk-1.0-0:
  Installed: 1.8.4-4
  Candidate: 1.8.4-4
  Version table:
 *** 1.8.4-4 500
        500 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

and the output for `ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-gtk-1.0.so.0 | grep local` is:

```
libclutter-1.0.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libclutter-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fb50b8e8000)
```

Comment: Please run two commands - `apt-cache policy libclutter-gtk-1.0-0` and `ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-gtk-1.0.so.0 | grep local` then add their output to the question body by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1302900/edit).

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove locally installed library with

```
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libclutter-1.0.so.0
```

and then retry launching GNOME Control Center.

Comment: this works but only temporarily.